# Show this function is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that the curve $x^a=y^b$ is irreducible if and only if $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

This is easy to prove if I consider the next function:

$$f:\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x^a-y^b\rangle\rightarrow\mathbb{C}[t]$$ such that $x\rightarrow t^b$ and $y\rightarrow t^a$, and show that $f$ is injective if $a$ and $b$ are coprime.
The first implication in our initial problem is easy to do by contradiction and the binomial formula on $(x^{a/d})^d - (y^{b/d})^d$ with $d=\gcd(a,b)$.
The other implication I have to use the function $f$ and the statement above, and then see its kernel is trivial (because I supposed it is injective) and then play with that.
I have all the problem done except the part that $f$ is injective if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, I can’t find the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. I've cleaned up the formatting on your question - could you please check that I haven't messed up the meaning of anything while doing so?

Comment: yes, it is perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that for any $p\in \Bbb C[x,y]/(x^a-y^b)$, we can write $p$ as $\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} x^ip_i(y)$: just use the relation $x^a=y^b$ to write $x^{a+i}=x^iy^b$ as many times as necessary. Now suppose that $f(\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} x^ip_i(y))=0$: substituting in $x=t^b$ and $y=t^a$, we get that $\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} t^{ib}p_i(t^a)=0$. Now look at the coefficients of each monomial term: since $\{0,b,2b,\dots,(a-1)b\}$ form a complete set of residue classes modulo $a$, we can't have any terms in common between $t^{ib}p_i(t^a)$ and $t^{jb}p_j(t^a)$ if $j\neq i$ (if we did, we'd have that $ib+na=jb+na$, or that $ib=jb$ modulo $a$). This implies that $p$ was zero to begin with, or that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Hi Hank, thanks for your answer, but how did you get the coefficients of the monomials and why is it a set of residue clases modulo a? Where do you use a and b are coprimes, in the last parenthesis?

Comment: @Laura I'm not sure what you mean by "the coefficients" - the first step just rewrites instances of $x^{a+i}$ as $x^iy^b$ so that we can represent our element $p$ as a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ where the maximum degree of $x$ appearing is $a-1$. From there, I write that polynomial as a sum of $x^i$ times a polynomial in $y$ as $i$ goes between $0$ and $a-1$. I hope that's clear? For the second bit, $a$ and $b$ coprime is exactly the condition that $\{0,b,2b,\cdots,(a-1)b\}$ forms a complete set of residue classes modulo $a$.

Comment: and why jb different from ib implies f has to be zero?

Comment: @Laura We assume $f(\sum x^ip_i(y))=0$ and are trying to show that this implies $\sum x^ip_i(y)=0$ so that $f$ is an injection. The proof is that coefficient of $t^{ib+na}$ in $f(\sum x^ip_i(y))$ is exactly the degree $n$ coefficient of $p_i$, so if all of these coefficients are zero, then all of the $p_i$ are zero, and so our original element was already zero, proving the claim.

Comment: the problem is, why f(p)=0 and the claim that the coefficients of the monomials are different from each other (I understand this now, thank you!) implies that every term of f(p) is zero? I mean can f(p) be zero because the terms cancel between them and not because they are all zero?

Comment: @Laura I don't understand your comment - $f(\sum x^ip_i(y))$ is a polynomial in $k[t]$, so it's zero iff all of it's coefficients are zero.

Comment: ahhhh nice, thank you so much Hank :)